# How can I show that $a^{2}-b^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{k}}$ has only two sets of solutions for $k=2$ and $a,b \neq 0$?

Tags: number-theory

We are having a hard time trying to prove that only 2 pairs of solutions for $a,b \neq 0$ will hold to the equation.

Comment: Just try some numbers. You are working mod 4 and $a,b \neq 0$ so there are only 9 possibilities.

Comment: Did you mean $a\not\equiv0 \pmod{2^k}$ and $b\not\equiv0 \pmod{2^k}$?

Answer (score 3):

You are working modulo $4$. And, modulo $4$, the only squares are $0$ and $1$.